# Set colors to specific cells dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `17x17` table which is generated dynamically using `jquery`. See below:

[image]

Below is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var number_of_rows = 17;
  var number_of_cols = 17;
  var table_body = '<table border="0">';
  for (var i = 0; i < number_of_rows; i++) {
    table_body += '<tr>';
    for (var j = 0; j < number_of_cols; j++) {
      table_body += '<td>';
      table_body += '<button id="row_' + i + '" class="col_' + j + '">&nbsp;</button>';
      table_body += '</td>';
    }
    table_body += '</tr>';
  }
  table_body += '</table>';
  $('#tableDiv').html(table_body);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tableDiv">
  Table will generate here.
</div>
```

My problem is that, I want to set the background color to red on specific cells just like the below table dynamically. I've done some researches, but still can't find the solution. 
[image]

Comment: Is the syntax error (missing `})` at the end of your Javascript) the cause of your issue, or is that solely a mistake in the question? Please compare the behavior that you're expecting to the behavior that you're seeing. I don't see any portion of code, CSS, etc, that would make the cells red.

Comment: sorry I've forgot the ending `})`

Comment: I've edited my question. Thank You for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a style var and assign it to a red background color if the row and col numbers are right:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var number_of_rows = 17;
  var number_of_cols = 17;
  var table_body = '<table border="0">';
  for (var i = 0; i < number_of_rows; i++) {
    table_body += '<tr>';
    for (var j = 0; j < number_of_cols; j++) {

      var style = "";
      if (Math.ceil(i / 3) % 2 !== 0 && j % 4 !== 0) {
        style = "background-color: red;";
      }

      table_body += '<td style="' + style + '">';
      table_body += '<button id="row_' + i + '" class="col_' + j + '" style="' + style + '">&nbsp;</button>';
      table_body += '</td>';
    }
    table_body += '</tr>';
  }
  table_body += '</table>';
  $('#tableDiv').html(table_body);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tableDiv">
  Table will generate here.
</div>
```

Comment: is there any way that this could be dynamic `if(i > 0 && i < 4 || i > 6 && i < 10 || i > 12 && i < 16)` depending on the declared `number_of_rows` and `number_of_cols`?

Comment: @Rigel1121 You're welcome, check out my edit for the dynamic part

Comment: Use `if (Math.ceil(i / 3) % 2 !== 0 && j % 4 !== 0)` instead if you prefer a simple version.

Comment: @Hikarunomemory I updated my answer, thanks for the code